# making arrays/lists of selected items from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

need some guidance with python dictionary, please help if you can..

**I have a dictionary which looks like (it has some 100 names, but i am showing you a sample):**

```
{'John':{'Maths':40,
        'Eng':50,
        'Phy':67,
        'Chem':78}
'Kate':{'Maths':98,
       'Chem':83}
'Julia':{'Phy':76,
         'Eng':67,
         'Maths':56,
         'Bio':78}
'Sam':{'Phy':23,
       'Eng':67,
       'Chem':98,
       'Maths':56}}
```

**What I want** is to make a table of two columns (or have two arrays) containing the names of the students and their respective English marks, **provided they do not have any marks for Bio.** (i.e. Julia's name should not be in the list).

Is it possible to do this elegantly in python? :-/

Comment: Yes it can be done quite elegantly. This would make a good homework question.

Comment: I am trying to use the my_dictionary.iteritems() with a for loop, but I am not being able to come up with a good solution..

Comment: @Panchi You should really post your code so far, so other people can comment on it what is actually wrong.

Comment: from next time, sure will!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `for` loop and some string formatting will do ([since we already have a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917333/142637)):

```
data = {'John': {'Maths': 40, 'Eng':50, 'Phy': 67, 'Chem': 78},
        'Kate': {'Maths': 98, 'Chem': 83},
        'Julia': {'Phy': 76, 'Eng': 67, 'Maths': 56, 'Bio': 78},
        'Sam': {'Phy': 23, 'Eng': 67, 'Chem': 98, 'Maths': 56}}

print "name\tmark\n------------"            
for name, marks in data.iteritems():
    if not 'Bio' in marks:
        print "{name}\t{mark}".format(name=name, mark=marks.get('Eng', '---'))
```

**Output:**

```
name    mark
------------
Sam     67
John    50
Kate    ---
```

---

In response to your comment:

Use the `zip`-function:

```
zip(*[(k,v['Eng']) for k,v in data.iteritems() if not 'Bio' in v and 'Eng' in v])
```

results in

```
[('Sam', 'John'), (67, 50)]
```

Comment: this works.. thanks :)

bdw, can I have these two coloumns of name and mark as two arrays like
    >> name = [sam, john]
    >> mark = [67,50]
???

if possible, i do not want kate in the list..

Comment: in  your first code, in place of "if not 'Bio' in marks", can we specify a value for the marks of Bio, like "if not the value of Bio equals 45 in marks"???

PS: if I want to remove only those students who have got one particular mark (say 45) in bio.. other students having some other marks in bio can stay in the list!!

Answer (score 2):

This does the job using a list comprehension, feel free to consider it elegant:

```
h = {'John': {'Maths': 40, 'Eng':50, 'Phy': 67, 'Chem': 78},
     'Kate': {'Maths': 98, 'Chem': 83},
     'Julia': {'Phy': 76, 'Eng': 67, 'Maths': 56, 'Bio': 78},
     'Sam': {'Phy': 23, 'Eng': 67, 'Chem': 98, 'Maths': 56}}
print [(k, v.get('Eng')) for k, v in h.iteritems() if 'Bio' not in v]
```

Output:

```
[('Sam', 67), ('John', 50), ('Kate', None)]
```

Use `print` in a `for` loop to format it as a table.

Comment: This will throw a KeyError.

Comment: this actually is throwing a KeyError.. is it because 'Eng' is not present for all the keys? For example, Kate does not have marks in english..